# How to optimize a nested query?

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

Can I somehow join tables and avoid the usage of distinct in the following MySQL query.
invited_by_id shows the user id of who invited this user.

```
SELECT
    user1.id, count(distinct user2.id) AS theCount, count(distinct user3.id) AS theCount2
FROM
    users AS user1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    users AS user2 ON user2.invited_by_id=user1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT id, invited_by_id FROM users WHERE signup_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
) AS user3 ON user3.invited_by_id=user1.id
GROUP BY user1.id;
```

Comment: Why would you need distinct? It seems to me that user X should only be allowed to be invited by user Y *one* time.

Comment: @Lieven Since the table is being joined in twice you can get duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, I changed the sub-query table names to make it a bit clearer:

```
Select
    user.id,
    all_time.total AS theCount, 
    last_month.total AS theCount2
From users AS user
Left Outer Join 
    (Select Count(id) as total, invited_by_id
     From users
     Group By invited_by_id) as all_time
       On all_time.invited_by_id = user.id
Left Outer Join
    (Select Count(id) as total, invited_by_id
     From users 
     Where signup_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
     Group By invited_by_id) AS last_month 
       On last_month.invited_by_id = user.id
```

If this is something you run often, make sure that `user.invited_by_id` is indexed!

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming here that you are trying to get a count of how many times a user has been invited and a count of how many times that user has been invited in the past 30 days.

In this case you could do the query with a simple conditional sum as :

```
select user1.id, count(user2.id) as tehCount, sum(user2.signup_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) as theCount2
from users as user1
left outer join users as user2 on user2.invited_by_id = user1.id
group by user1.id
```

If the nulls in theCount2 will be a problem, use a coalesce as :

```
coalesce(sum(user2.signup_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a version of MySQL greater than 5.0.37 you have a [Profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html) available to you that could give you a pretty good idea of where the bottlenecks are on any query. That might be a good starting point- you could maybe edit the output into the original question if you're not sure about how best to interpret it.

Comment: Ah... That makes a lot more sense now! :)